# How to define Id as variable

Tags: jquery

Let say

```
 <div id = "test_id" class = "test_class"> </div>
```

***JS***

```
  alert( $("#test_id").hasClass('test_class') );  // result is true
```

I just write another way to get the same expected result but didn't work, Why?

```
 var test = ' " ' + "test_id" + ' " ' ;

      alert( $(test).hasClass('test_class')  );    // not working, why ?????
```

Comment: ohh great thanks to all of you. my silly mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'test' needs to be in the format of an ID selector - i.e. `#test`

So it should be:

```
var test = '#test_id';
alert( $(test).hasClass('test_class') );
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can't assign a variable like that. The `var` is a keyword which signifies a variable declaration is about to occur. Get rid of the first `=` sign.

Secondly, you have included the `"` characters in your string. Those are used to declare a String literal, which is what you pass into the jQuery function in your first example. They are not part of the string itself.

Third, you didn't include the `#` character at the start of the selector in your second example.

If you change your second example to:

```
var test = '#test_id';
```

then it should work just fine.

Comment: yes, it was typing mistake (var = test = '#test_id';) . sorry for that. anyway thanks for notice

Answer (score 0):

How about now?

```
var test = '#test_id'; // no need for the inner double quotes

alert( $(test).hasClass('test_class') );
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the #:

```
 var test = '#test_id';

  alert( $(test).hasClass('test_class')  );    // should be working now
```

Answer (score 0):

You are double-quoting the ID stored in `test`:

```
var test = ' " ' + "test_id" + ' " ' ; // test == '"test_id"' == broken
```

Just do `var test = "test_id"`, and don't forget to prepend the `#`

Answer (score 0):

1. you forgot the "#"
2. the ' " ' is not necessary
3. you have two equals..

var = test = ' " ' + "test_id" + ' " ' ; //<-- this is wrong

var test = "#test_id"; // <-- this is ok

you are missing some basic skills. probably a tutorial would be useful to clear some basic things up.